# Porque '08' gera erro dentro do Eclipe?

Tags: java

Tenho uma classe com '`int = dia, mes e ano`' e na outra estou chamando eles. Só que me chamou atenção foi que, quando coloco o valor '08' diz

> 'The literal 08 of type int is out of range'.

mas quando coloco 07, compila sem problemas.

Vou inserir os códigos:

```
    public class Data {
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
}
```

---

```
    public class DataTeste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Data nascimento = new Data();
        **nascimento.dia = 08;**--este valor da erro, mas 07 p/baixo valida.
        nascimento.mes = 03;
        nascimento.ano = 1989;
    }
}
```

Comment: Primeiramente, porque criar uma classe para data se o java tem tantas classes para isso?

Comment: É que estou seguindo um exemplo de uma vídeo aula...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qualquer número prefixado com 0 é considerado octal. Os números octais só podem usar os dígitos 0 a 7, assim como o decimal pode usar 0-9 e o binário pode usar 0-1.

// octal to decimal

01  // 1

02  // 2

07  // 7

010 // 8

020 // 16

// octal to binary (excluding most significant bit)

01  // 1

02  // 10

07  // 111

010 // 1000

020 // 10000

Ou seja, internamente o seu "dia" esta tendo 3 números.

Comment: Muito obrigado, entendi o porque do erro

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que na maioria das linguagens um número inteiro literal iniciado por zero é interpretado como sendo uma valor octal, é por isso que até o 07 dá certo por não existir uma representação em octal desses números o certo seria você nunca iniciar um número com 0.

Comment: Entendi...
MUITO OBRIGADO DE VERDADE